# Test files in classpath

Tags: grails, jenkins, classpath

Ive created a folder resources under test/integration path to store data files that will be used during integration test phase.

I use then

```
private static final Resource jsonCategory = new ClassPathResource("resources/testdata.json")
```

It's working on local with simple test-app (no special options) however when jenkings takes the code and try to run the tests they are failing because

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/testdata.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I've checked that files are in the same location ... but it seems that by unknown reason jenking cannot find them in the classpath.

Might this be possible? ... do you have any idea about how to make jenkins resolve the same classpath i have in my local?

By the way the command line that jenkins uses looks like:

```
grails -Dgrails.work.dir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myapp-develop//target -Dgrails.env=TEST clean --non-interactive --plain-output --refresh-dependencies
```

What i can see is that those files are not in that work.dir ... shall them be there?

Comment: I've realized that if i remove the --non-interactive it works (?!?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your file under `test/resources/testdata.file` and access it via `new File("test/resources/testdata.file`).

Comment: I cannot use an absolute path since it may change out of my scope ... thats why i try to seach in the classpath

Comment: However using that folder and the same 
"new ClassPathResource("test/resources/testdata.json")" worked!